# Creating application for multiple clients

Tags: asp.net-core

I have built an application and installed it for a client and it is working without any issues. Now a second client wants to use it and he asked me to do some changes in some areas in the application. How can I handle these changes because the first client might not like them?

I thought of creating one project for each client, but the duplication of the common code will be big. So could you please help me by direct me to any resources I can read or use for this?

Comment: You can’t make everyone happy! They both will use what your app is offering.

Comment: what is the `some areas` . if just some properties, you can add related column in table and distinguish clients by specific value.

Comment: @Nan Yu, for example the first client asked me to modify one of the views to fit his business. The second client doesn't need this changes. And same with the logic the first client asked to modify the logic where the other client does not want this change.